# Refreshing console value without system("cls");

Tags: c, console, refresh

I'm trying to write Snake in C, but at the moment I've just written a variable length and width matrix. Since I want that the game (so the map) is continously refreshing I tried to write the code this way, but the "refreshing effect" is not so good to see. What can I do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int larghezza = 0, altezza = 0, i = 0, j = 0, **griglia;

    printf("Inserire la larghezza della mappa(max 79):");
    while(scanf("%d", &larghezza) == 1) /* Inserimento larghezza */
    {
        if(larghezza >= 15 && larghezza <= 79)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Numero di larghezza non valido.\n");
            continue;
        }
    }

    printf("Inserire l'altezza della matrice:");
    while(scanf("%d", &altezza) == 1) /* Inserimento altezza */
    {
        if(altezza >= 15 && altezza <= 79)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Numero di altezza non valido.\n");
            continue;
        }
    }

    griglia = malloc(altezza * sizeof(int*));  /* griglia si estende solo in larghezza */
    for(i = 0; i < altezza; i++)
    {
        griglia[i] = malloc(larghezza * sizeof(int)); /* poi ogni elemento "i" di griglia */
    }                                               /*avrà una lunghezza pari ad "altezza" */

    for(i = 0; i < altezza; i++) /* Inizializza la matrice griglia */
    {
        for(j = 0; j < larghezza; j++)
        {
            griglia[i][j]= 254;
        }
    }

    while(1) /* refresh infinito mappa */
    {
        for(i = 0; i < altezza; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < larghezza; j++)
            {
                printf("%c", griglia[i][j]);
            } /* end for colonne */
            printf("\n");
        } /*end for righe */
        Sleep(100);
        system("cls");
    }/* end while di refresh */
```

Comment: Update only the spaces which 'use' the snake, and the void spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear just the last position where the snake were.

I would just clear the last char at the end of the snake. This way the refreshing problem would cease, you have only to control the size of the snake and position (you will need anyway to do that).

Cheers,

LEslie

Comment: Which instruments I need to do that? Because I'm new in C programming and I just know loops, vectors, and some other little things.

Comment: Granpasso, you'll need a library to draw it for you. You can give a try to  ncurses http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses . Cheers

Comment: Perhaps, `gotoxy` from `conio.h` also helps for that case. If so, leave `ncurses` for future :-)